# individual characters treated as string in javascript arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, arguments

I need to write a function that retrieves the last parameter passed into the function. If it's just arguments, it should return the last element. If it's a string, it should return the last character. Arrays should return the last element of the array. My code works for arrays, strings and arguments as long as they are not all strings.

```
function last(list){
  var arr;
  if(list instanceof Array){
    return list[list.length-1];
  }
  if(typeof list === 'string' || list instanceof String){
    arr = list.split("");
    return arr[arr.length-1];
  }

  return arguments[arguments.length-1];
}
```

This works for almost every case, but I have a problem when the input is a bunch of string arguments.

```
Test.assertEquals(last('a','b','c','z'), 'z');
```

returns 'a'

Why are disjoint strings evaluating to true when testing if the arguments are arrays or strings and how can I universaly access the last value of arbitrary parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do that

```
function last(){
    var a = arguments;
    return (a.length > 1 ? [].slice.call(a) :
            typeof a[0] === 'string' ? a[0].split('') : a[0]).pop();
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2pppmahu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your function call to `Test.assertEquals(last(['a','b','c','z']), 'z');`

Whereas before you were passing four different arguments to `last()`, this passes a single argument, a list containing four characters.

Comment: That's not an acceptable work around. The function needs to be able to accept arrays, strings and arguments. A test case provided was Test.assertEquals(last(1,"b",3,"d",5), 5); and my code works because it drops down to the last return statement, but the disjoint characters are being read as a string and it's getting into the second if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Change your last function like this:

```
function last(list){
  var arr;
  if(list instanceof Array){
    return list[list.length-1];
  }
  if((typeof list === 'string' || list instanceof String) && (arguments.length == 1)){
    arr = list.split("");
    return arr[arr.length-1];
  }

  return arguments[arguments.length-1];
};
```